# jQuery animation but not simultaneously ?

Tags: jquery, animation

http://jsbin.com/ilemoy/2/edit

I've build some code but the animation runs at the `same` time.

My question is :

What is the `approach` ( I don't need the code actually - althught it will be great) for `remembering` in queue the "*need to come*" animations ?

example :

when I mouse over from left to right all over the items :

the `first` one will animate , the `second..last` animations should be "remembered" to be animated  .

the first  animation finishes , and **THEN** starts the second animations for the second one.

when it finishes , the third one begins etc...

*What is the best practice approach ?*

I thought about declaring an array and each mouse over should push the object - and when the animation finished , it pop the next item and animate the selected item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the example on this page: http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/y8Rtx/

Comment: I know the queue command. the animations here are auto in queue. but how do i remember the need to come animations ?